# Is there any info on the 1 Feb 2016 Portal 2 Patch?

Tags: portal-2

I just got a seemingly-random 8.0 MB patch for Portal 2. The [Portal 2 News](http://store.steampowered.com/news/?ap) page has nothing on it, nor does the [portal wiki](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Patches). All I found online was a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Portal/comments/43r8m1/portal_2_update/) page asking the same question with no answers. The reddit users seem to think it may be a VR patch, but I don't have any VR options in my menu after the update.

Is there any information about what was added/changed with the patch?

Comment: It is common place to install a large patch containing a future update.  If it is VR they would just change a variable to show them when they are ready.

Answer (score 13):

There is a [huge thread on steamcommunity.com](https://steamcommunity.com/app/620/discussions/0/483367798518556863/#p1) about an update from several months ago causing Portal 2 to have terrible performance on Macs.  According to [two](https://steamcommunity.com/app/620/discussions/0/451852571443085823/#c451852571443162108) [users](https://steamcommunity.com/app/620/discussions/0/483367798518556863/#c405690850600523642), this update fixes that issue.

This is most anyone currently knows, there hasn't been any official word or reverse-engineering from the community yet.